# unknown characters %252B in url

Tags: php, encoding, ascii, urlencode

i have a page with links gotten from rss. they are:
broken link

```
http://news.asiaone.com/News/Latest%252BNews/Singapore/Story/A1Story20121220-390687.html
```

working link

```
http://news.asiaone.com/News/Latest%2BNews/Singapore/Story/A1Story20121220-390687.html
```

i realise it works by changing %252B to %2B. im using php. is there a way to detect and correct it on the run?

Comment: Just use `str_replace('%252B', '%25%2B', 'URLHERE')`

Answer (score 18):

The URL has been double encoded. `%25` is the escape sequence for "%", so a regular `%2B` got escaped again to `%252B`.

`urldecode` the value, but better avoid double-encoding it to begin with if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use "urldecode"

```
echo urldecode("http://news.asiaone.com/News/Latest%252BNews/Singapore/Story/A1Story20121220-390687.html");
```